# NTP server in windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ntp

I am a bit confused..I installed MS server 2012 on machine and I added it to domain..Over this 2012 server I installed active directory for test purpose.. Then I configured w32tm over domain controller over MS server 2012 and every thing fine.. But, I found litter another NTP server was configured on my network and clients resync from it.. It was the PDC..

my question is: How Can I force client to take time from my NTP server, not from PDC??

Comment: `1.` I don't understand what you did? Could you rephrase your question? `2.` Domain members will sync with their authenticating DC, whether that be the PDCe or another DC, why would you want to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that there's absolutely no reason to do this, you could achieve this using GPO and explicit timeserver assignment.

Comment: simply I added windows server to a domain in order to configure it as NTP server.

Comment: .after I done configuration I tried to let client to resync their time with my NTP server..But, I found they resync from other NTP server(PDC)..

Comment: how can I force client to resync their time from my NTP server??

Comment: If you want the functional outcome of your clients syncing with the NTP server, then have the PDC sync its time from that server. I don't recommend this, but that will effectively do what you want.

Comment: @Mr.Ali This answer is an answer to your question. If you don't understand this answer, then you can ask questions about it, but I will mention that if you're not sure what a GPO is maybe you should ask a professional to help you with your network.

Comment: @Mr.Ali: Why are you so intent on changing the default behavior for time synchronization in the domain? What is your end goal? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: another question.. should I install ntp server on domain controller??

Comment: This is actually already the case - by default. Your client's are already using it obviously.